# AutoThread class in Delphi VCL?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

Does the Delphi VCL/RTL have something like an AutoThread class? I.e., every method of a class derived from e.g. TAutoThread class would then **AUTOMATICALLY** be executed in a separate thread, without having to write any thread specific code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using an [`Anonymous thread`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Classes.TThread.CreateAnonymousThread) it is possible to make something similar as an AutoThread class.

Just pass an anonymous procedure and invoke the thread.

```
var
  aThread : TThread;
...
aThread := 
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
       // your code to execute in a separate thread here.
    end
  );
aThread.Start; // start thread and it will execute and self terminate
```

Note, this has nothing to do with a class derived from another class, but the result is similar. You don't have to write any thread specific code. Of cource, you will have to follow normal thread rules.

---

If you need to get notified when the thread has finished, define an `OnTerminate` method before starting the thread. It will be executed in the main thread.

```
aThread.OnTerminate := Self.ThreadFinishedNotification;
```

Comment: From inside of such a thread procedure, can I use variables and objects from "outside"?

Comment: I've just tested using variables and objects from "outside" from inside of such a thread procedure, and it works with no problems.

Comment: @user1580348, accessing variables and objects outside is possible, but keep in mind that this could be unsafe, depending on you implementation. Accessing VCL without proper protection is a no-no for example.

Comment: How could this be prevented? Can ´Synchronize´ be used from inside this Thread procedure?

Comment: Yes, `TThread.Synchronize( nil, procedure begin UpdateComponent(...); end);` or if you want an asynch update, `TThread.Queue(nil, procedure begin UpdateComponent(...); end);`.

Answer (score 3):

As alternative to the build in thread class, you really should check the [omnithreadlibrary](http://code.google.com/p/omnithreadlibrary/).

This is more efficient, because there are schedulers, async'n wait methods and thread synchronization build in. 
Some high level functions like foreach.parallel (know from .net) is also available.

With OmniThreadLibrary you can simply execute a code in a thread.

```
Async(
  procedure begin
    // threaded code
  end).Await(
  procedure begin
    // main thread code, will be executed after threaded code finishes
  end);
```

Comment: Thx gabr ;-) this year on delphi days was also a session about your framework.